# WPF Adding style resource without key in code behind

Tags: wpf

I'm generating a xaml from the code behind of a WPF application and want to add styles to the generated xaml. I'm using a resource dictionary to store the styling info which my app will access and apply to the appropriate elements in the generated xaml based on keys in the resource dictionary. Now I want to apply a specific style to all textboxes in the generated xaml. What I'm trying to do is to create this style in the resource dictionary without a key and I want to add this style resource to the resources of the generated xaml. I can't seem to find a way to add a particular resource to the resource dictionary of this generated xaml without a key. My questions is, is it possible to do so, i.e. add a resource to the resource dictionary of a usercontrol (or window etc.) without a key for that resource?

For example, here is the XAML I want to generate:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <!--The TextBox style-->
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So, I found a way to do this. While adding to the resources of the generated xaml instead of specifying a string key, I used typeof(TextBox) and that seemed to work.

```
UserControl.Resources.Add(typeof(TextBox), styleDictionary["TextBoxStyleKey"]);
```

This results in:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <!--The Style-->
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Is there a better way(or any other way) of doing this?

Comment: FYI, this works because if you do not add `x:Key`, the TargetType is used as the key instead.