# In C# WPF, how would I programmatically set a group of RadioButtons to have the characteristics of a ToggleButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, code-behind

In the Window designer, I would make a group of RadioButtons to have the characteristics of a ToggleButton like this:

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="ToolPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton x:Name="button_DrawNode" Click="Button_DrawNode_Checked" Content="Draw"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="button_Connect" Click="Button_Connect_Checked" Content="Connect"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="button_Move" Click="Button_Move_Checked" Content="Move"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="button_Remove" Click="Button_Remove_Checked" Content="Remove"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In code behind, I would create a StackPanel and then the subsequent RadioButtons like this:

```cs
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel
{
    Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
};

Grid.SetRow(stackPanel, 0);

RadioButton button_DrawNode = new RadioButton { Content = "Draw" };
RadioButton button_Connect = new RadioButton { Content = "Connect" };
RadioButton button_Move = new RadioButton { Content = "Move" };
RadioButton button_Remove = new RadioButton { Content = "Remove" };

stackPanel.Children.Add(button_DrawNode);
stackPanel.Children.Add(button_Connect);
stackPanel.Children.Add(button_Move);
stackPanel.Children.Add(button_Remove);
```

However, scouring the Internet, I could not find an example of code behind to achieve the following tags:

```xml
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

To my understanding, putting a Style tag (like the one above) within the StackPanel.Resources tag will make all RadioButtons within the StackPanel have the characteristics of a ToggleButton, only needing to set it once.

In the following code, I can set the Style property for each RadioButton instance to make them behave as a ToggleButton, but I feel that would be unnecessarily repeating code.

```cs
Style toggleRadioButtonStyle = new Style(typeof(RadioButton), (Style)FindResource(typeof(ToggleButton)));
RadioButton button_DrawNode = new RadioButton { Content = "Draw", Style = toggleRadioButtonStyle };
RadioButton button_Connect = new RadioButton { Content = "Connect", Style = toggleRadioButtonStyle };
RadioButton button_Move = new RadioButton { Content = "Move", Style = toggleRadioButtonStyle };
RadioButton button_Remove = new RadioButton { Content = "Remove", Style = toggleRadioButtonStyle };
```

I tried to experiment with the following, thinking that the StackPanel's Style property set the StackPanel.Resources tag.

```cs
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel
{
    Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
    Style = new Style(typeof(RadioButton), (Style)FindResource(typeof(ToggleButton)))
};
```

The result:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** ''RadioButton' TargetType does not match type of element 'StackPanel'.'

I concluded that the Style property of StackPanel is only to set it's own style.

I also looked at the Resources property of StackPanel but InteliSense says it only takes a ResourceDictionary.

Any help or insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping Radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620071/grouping-radio-button)

Comment: In the first place, why you apply default Style of ToggleButton to RadioButton? If you don't like the default appearance of RadioButton, just customize it.

Comment: @quaabaam, I want to know how to do the <StackPanel.Resources><Style/></StackPanel.Resources>, as explain above, in C# code.

Comment: @emoacht, the reason I did this was because I want to have Buttons to act as a RadioButton because I wanted to make a tool pannel with one selectable tool at a time. I don't remember where on stackoverflow but I saw that was a solution that was presented for the issue of having a Button act as a RadioButton.

Comment: @Experiment-626 So what is your problem with default RadioButton?

Comment: [Defining StackPanel resources programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960904/defining-stackpanel-resources-programmatically)

Comment: @emoacht, I don't have a problem with the default RadioButton other than the fact they don't look like Buttons. I know I can customize it visually, but as I said, at the time, that was the suggestion that I saw and decided to go with that. However, my reason for using the RadioButton as a ToggleButton is irrelevant. I want to know how to add styles in general to a Panel type as explained above. I assume that if I have several styles that I want to apply that I would place them between the Panal.Resources tag. If that is the case, I want to know how to do it programmatically.

Comment: @quaabaam, I have seen that post before. That doesn't quite explain how to add Styles to the . Resources tag. The entry to using resources that way is having a key and and object associated with the key. I do not see how that helps me, but I appreciate your effort in trying to help. If I am mistaken, and this is how you do it, I am sure there is more to do than what is shown in that post.

Comment: Why are you defining UI in code at all?  The recommended way to build truly dynamic UI is to define xaml as a string and use xamlreader.parse to create the controls.  With that approach you can paste xaml into a scratch window and check it works.

Comment: @Andy, do you have any links that could point me into the right direction to implement such a UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the title of this question is confusing and building visual elements in code behind is not generally recommended unless it is truly necessary.

That said, your mistake is obvious. You need to set the Style for RadioButton to the StackPanel's Resources, as you did in xaml, but not to the StackPanel's Style. To do so, Duke Cyrillus's answer to [WPF Adding style resource without key in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10834321/3137337) is useful.

```cs
var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
stackPanel.Resources.Add(typeof(RadioButton), (Style)FindResource(typeof(ToggleButton)));
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried it and it worked. I am relatively new to WPF programming and did not understand the concept of a key with tags. I have seen tags use keys but I did not understand that this was basically the same thing. As I mentioned in my original post, I saw that the Resources property only used ResourceDictionary. What I failed mention was when I tried Resources.Add, that it wanted an Object Key and an Object Value. I did not associate the Style tag with this input.